# Generate alter syntax for column

Tags: php, mysql, create-table, alter, describe

I've found a way to find missing tables between two databases, and missing columns from intersect tables. I can get "create" syntax for missing tables, but how do I generate "alter" syntax for missing columns?
Is there something like `SHOW CREATE TABLE $table` for column?
@Edit
I get:

```
CREATE TABLE `table` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(225) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

by `SHOW CREATE TABLE $table`

-> I figure out the second database's "table" misses "name" column. How do I "parse" (?) this create to generate alter to add column "name" to the second database's table?

Comment: It's described [in the manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html). Please update your question if you need assistance with understanding what's described in the manual. The relevant bits are `ALTER TABLE tbl_name [ADD | ALTER | CHANGE] col_name`.

Comment: I need to GENERATE this alter, not write it myself. I don't know anything about column beside name, and I need to generate proper alter to include keys, field types etc.

Comment: Alright, but doesn't [`SHOW CREATE TABLE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-create-table.html) also output relevant information about columns? I'm not entirely sure what the problem is, you are facing. But that could be me, misunderstanding your question. Perhaps you could expand your question with an example of how you are generating the syntax now and give more details of where you are struggling with the columns part.

Comment: Ok, so I get: CREATE TABLE `table` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(225) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) and then figure out the second db's "table" misses "name". How do I turn this into "alter" to add "name"?

Comment: Please use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44109066/edit) function to expand on your question. Too much code in comments can get messy rather quickly. :-) It also helps keep a better overview of the additional information you have given us. Thanks!

Comment: @DecentDabbler done

Comment: Thanks @Saus. I understand what you are trying to do now and I think [@NigelRen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44109493) gives a good starting point.

Answer (score 1):

If you want individual columns, then use ( change users to your table name )

```
show columns from users
```

If this is done on both tables, you can check the differences.  This may include having to alter columns if the definition has changed.
To add a new column, use something like

```
alter table users add column email varchar(255) after name
```

The after bit allows you to position the new column at the same place as in your other table (makes it look consistent in query tools).